# fromEvent/fromEventPattern - removal not happening on unsubscribe if its pipe has startWith

Tags: rxjs

I was using `fromEvent` but I switched to `fromEventPattern` so I can `console.log` to troubleshoot. I see that when I `unsubscribe()`, only the first `fromEventPattern` remove method is called. Does anyone know why the remove handlers of the the `window.remveEventListener('online')` and `offline` are not getting called?

If I remove the `startWith(window.navigator.onLine)` from the the `.pipe` it works, but I need the the `startWith(window.navigator.onLine)` for at least one of them.

Here is my pipeline:

```js
pipeline$ = combineLatest(
    merge(
        fromEventPattern(
            handler => {
                console.log('adding io.socket.disconnect');
                io.socket.on('disconnect', handler);
            },
            handler => {
                console.log('removing io.socket.disconnect');
                io.socket.off('disconnect', handler);
            },
        ).pipe(
            mapTo(false),
            tap(() => this.setState({ isConnected: false })),
        ),
        this.isConnectedSubject.pipe(
            tap(isConnected => this.setState({ isConnected })),
            startWith(io.socket.isConnected())
        )
    ),
    merge(
        fromEventPattern(
            handler => {
                console.log('adding window.online');
                window.addEventListener('online', handler, false);
            },
            handler => {
                console.log('removing window.online');
                window.removeEventListener('online', handler, false);
            }
        ).pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('online')),
            mapTo(true),
            tap(() => this.setState({ isOnline: true })),
            startWith(window.navigator.onLine)
        ),
        fromEventPattern(
            handler => {
                console.log('adding window.offline');
                window.addEventListener('offline', handler, false);
            },
            handler => {
                console.log('removing window.offline');
                window.removeEventListener('offline', handler, false);
            }
        ).pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('offline')),
            mapTo(false),
            tap(() => this.setState({ isOnline: false })),
            startWith(window.navigator.onLine)
        )
    )
).pipe(
    switchMap(([ isConnected, isOnline, ...rest ]) => {
        console.log('isConnected:', isConnected, 'isOnline:', isOnline, 'rest:', rest);
        console.log(!isConnected && isOnline ? 'RE-CON now' : 'DO NOT re-con');
        return !isConnected && isOnline
            ? defer(() => connectSocket()).pipe(
                retryWhen(error$ =>
                    error$.pipe(
                        tap(error => console.log('got socket connect error!', error.message)),
                        delayWhen((_, i) => {
                            const retryIn = 10000;
                            this.setState({
                                retryAt: Date.now() + retryIn
                            });
                            return timer(retryIn);
                        })
                    )
                ),
                tap(() => isConnectedSubject.next(true))
            )
            : EMPTY;
    }),
    takeUntil(mSessionSubject.pipe(
        filter(action => action.type === 'LOGOUT'),
    ))
);
```

I subscribe to it like this:

```
const sub = pipeline$.subscribe();
```

and then I unsubscribe like this:

```
sub.unsubscribe();
```

After calling this unsubscribe, I am not seeing the `online`/`offline` removal methods trigger.

Comment: what is `this.tap(...)`? Note that you aren't returning `timer` inside `delayWhen`. Also, add error handling to `subscribe`, at least for debugging. Aside from that it looks fine. Have you tried to reproduce it with a smaller, in a nutshell code?

Comment: Thanks @kos! I missed those. I wrapped the `.subscribe` in a `try { pipeline.subscribe() } catch(err) { console.log('err:', err) }`, Im still having the issue of only the first `fromEventPattern` triggering :( I'll try with smaller and build it up again. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @kos - oh wow, if i remove the `startWith` then it does trigger then removal method, this is so weird. Why does this happen? I need it to remove even if it has `startWith`.

Comment: Regarding error handling, I meant something like `.subscribe({ next: console.log, error: console.error, complete: ()=>console.log('done') })`, no need for `try-catch` there. `startWith` — hm, thats strange, can't see how it is related. Can you create a reproducible example? Say on stackblitz, or by adding a runnable snippet in your question: would be easier for us to help.

Comment: Thanks @kos I'll work on creating an example, at work now, will do soon.

Comment: Gosh @kos this is absurd lol, I can't reproduce it even though its pretty much exactly the same - just no react - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-y7bzjt?file=index.ts - I'll keep trying

Comment: I only can add that I had similar issue when I had **two** versions of rxjs chained together. E.g. I had `timer` from `rxjs` and, say, `takeUntil` from `rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.js`. Took me full 4 days to figure that out :) *Though I'm sure its not your case*

Comment: Oh wow thanks for sharing that case. It gives me motivation to keep digging! I really appreciate the morale support! I felt like giving up!

Comment: There are always solutions and workarounds. If you give up — you fail. If you proceed — you'll eventually find a way. So, good luck!

Comment: Wow @kos it might be electron - this guy is also having the same problem - https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/2138 - I asked him if he solved it.

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the subscription is defined before doing unsubscribe?
something like

```
if (sub !== undefined) {
  sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

because you might unsubscribe before `sub` emit any data however [It's not recommended to use unsubscribe](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) , but you could use `take(n)`, 
`takeWhile(predicate)`, `first()` or `first(predicate)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @sarea - that's a great point I didn't think about. Does it matter if `unsubscribe()` happens before any data is emitted? I am doing `unsubscribe()` in the unmount of my component, as the articles recommend. Only one place.